# SQL query for finding UNITS in EACH category ordered on each day of the week for the items

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

Below are the details I need:

1. Finding Units in EACH category that have been ordered on each day of the week in the last 7 days.
   -- Output as:

```
Category | Sunday_units | Monday_units | Tuesday_units | Wednesday_units | Thursday_units | Friday_units | Saturday_units
```

2. Finding the second earliest ORDER_ID for each customer for each date they placed AT LEAST two orders

   I also want to develop ER model with mappings for these tables. For developing an ER model with cardinality, I think : 1 item --> can have 1 or many orders
                      1 Order ---> Can have only one Item (As per the schema)
   Please validate if the model cardinality looks fine.

I tried finding the SQL server query using case statement.

Schema:

ORDERS

```
order_id varchar(20) composite primary key
customer_id numeric(35,0)
order_datetime timestamp
item_id varchar(10) composite primary key
order_quantity numeric(35,0)
```

Sample extract from ORDERS

```
order_id | customer_id | order_datetime | item_id | order_quantity
A-001    | 32483       | 2018-12-15 09:15:22 | B000 | 3                 
A-005    | 21456       | 2019-01-12 09:28:35 | B001 | 1
A-005    | 21456       | 2019-01-12 09:28:35 | B005 | 1
A-006    | 42491       | 2019-01-16 02:52:07 | B008 | 2
```

ITEMS

```
item_id varchar(10) primary key
item_category varchar(18)
```

Sample extract from ITEMS

```
item_id | item_category
B000 | Outdoors
B001 | Outdoors
B002 | Outdoors
B003 | Kitchen
B004 | Kitchen
```

The query I created is as below:

Looking at the query, how can we know that 01-10-2019 will fall on thursday? I want to also know about the date and corresponding week calculations.

```
Select i.item_category, 
    Sum(case when o.order_datetime = '01-10-2019' THEN o.Count(order_quantity) else null end) as Thursday_Units,
    Sum(case when o.order_datetime = '01-11-2019' THEN o.Count(order_quantity) else null end) as Friday_Units,
    Sum(case when o.order_datetime = '01-12-2019' THEN o.Count(order_quantity) else null end) as Saturday_Units,
    Sum(case when o.order_datetime = '01-13-2019' THEN o.Count(order_quantity) else null end) as Sunday_Units,
    Sum(case when o.order_datetime = '01-14-2019' THEN o.Count(order_quantity) else null end) as Monday_Units,
    Sum(case when o.order_datetime = '01-15-2019' THEN o.Count(order_quantity) else null end) as Tuesday_Units,
    Sum(case when o.order_datetime = '01-16-2019' THEN o.Count(order_quantity) else null end) as Wednesday_Units
from Orders o
inner join Items i on o.item_id = i.item_id
group by i.item_category
```

Comment: You can use DATENAME(W,getdate()) for determining the day of the week. Also, you could use PIVOT for your solution instead of CASE.

Comment: Your schema is in need of some serious review. OrderDateTime should NOT be timestamp. That datatype has no relationship to time or date. The other columns are also problematic. Don't just blindly choose datatypes. And you will find that an order usually consists of multiple items - you are most likely missing a table (or more).

Comment: `order_datetime` in `Orders` is a [`timestamp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It bears no relation to a [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If it did, then comparing it to midnight on a given date would be unlikely to match unless you happen to get a lot of nocturnal orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datename()`:

```
select 
    i.item_category, 
    sum(case when datename(weekday, o.order_datetime) = 'Sunday' then order_quantity end) as sunday_units,
    sum(case when datename(weekday, o.order_datetime) = 'Monday' then order_quantity end) as monday_units,
    ...
    sum(case when datename(weekday, o.order_datetime) = 'Saturday' then order_quantity end) as saturday_units,
from orders o 
inner join items i  on o.item_id = i.item_id
where o.order_datetime >= dateadd(day, -7, cast(getdate() as date))
group by i.item_category
```

I also added a `where` clause that filters on the last 7 days. Note that with this technique, the columns do not represent sequential dates (if today is a Monday, the data for the last Friday is more recent than the data of the last Tuesday).